# Users that are polluting the site

Tags: discussion, support

I'm an infrequent user on SE, but recently, I've been trying to get back into it and I'm finding that a huge amount of answers on here are just plain wrong.

There is one user in particular (Serpyre), that appears to post the same fictional response to almost every single answer on the site. Every time I come across one of his answers, it infuriates me. They aren't just wrong, there's absolutely no hint of truth and only serves as a way to promote his own development/hosting/consultancy services. I've no objection to professionals participating on here and helping others, but when the answers are blatently wrong and only serve to channel business to them - its out of order.

Normally, SE self regulates, but its not happening at the moment becase of the huge influx of 1 point "Hit and run" refugees from the Magento forums.

So these incorrect, and frankly dangerous answers, remain on the website. I have flagged, downvoted and commented wherever possible - but the moderators should really step in and either ban this user or delete the junk posts.

In the interests of just salvaging some answers, I've edited the advertisements out, but he persists in adding them back in.

Eg. https://magento.stackexchange.com/posts/30258/revisions

This is just ridiculous!

Comment: Hah, I think I remember coming across one of this answers. There were a lot of numbers. Very specific numbers.

Answer (score 1):

I see your point but so far there's no valid reason to delete this user. Please keep downvoting and flagging the answers which are in fact not and moderators will do the rest.

Also please note the fact that wrong answer is not a reason for deleting, only non-sense answers or spam.

Also please refrain from offence I see in your comments from time to time.

Anyways, thanks for your activity.

Comment: There is literally not one answer that he has posted that is correct. I can live with the self promotion if what he was saying was actually correct. But his answers are unbelievably wrong. Eg. http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/26118/500 - he doesn't even know that SOLR uses Lucene as its engine?! His answers are damaging to the community and the poor people who believe him. He just invents answers, based on no fact, and are almost always completely wrong. But there isn't enough people on here to correct/downvote his answers.

Comment: And again here, http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/25580/500 and here http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/13192/i-am-looking-for-a-quality-search-plugin/24707#24707

Comment: Well, wrong answer is still an answer but duplicate answer is bad.

Comment: After all I decided to delete this user. Thank you for your help and patience.

Comment: Come on Tim. I know you need to be unbiased as a mod. but even you can see how ridiculous his answers are?! Thank god he is gone. I want this site to help people, and he is doing the opposite.

Comment: And again http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/6010/providing-site-wide-search-for-community-edition/13691#13691

Comment: Down voting isn't working as it keeps getting reversed. I don't know what to do here.

Comment: The user deleting is not immediate. This account is scheduled to be deleted in 10 hours.

Comment: The troll is back, http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/33396/what-aspects-should-be-considered-for-creating-separate-nodes-of-magento-on-aws/38694?noredirect=1#comment58006_38694